# How to "Import in flutterTest Widget"

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

I'm a beginner in the developers world and i'm getting myself ready with Udemy Assit Video tutorial by Paul Dichone so i'm having a little problem which i need help on.

this is what am supposed to import
`'import: ./ui/home.dart';` in containers and layouts so i'm using visual studio code and what it gives me is 
`'import 'package:intro_layout_containers/ui/home.dart';`

How am i going to get it right?

Answer (score 1):

These two are equivalent.

It is just a different syntax:

- `import './ui/home.dart';` is a relative import
- `import 'package:intro_layout_containers/ui/home.dart';` is an absolute import.

But the imported file is the same

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, i was confused and to spit it out here.